# Error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'StreamingContext' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have these errors when trying to write this script for save and load in my game.

> Assets\Scripts\Save System\SaveData.cs(62,40): error CS0246: The type
> or namespace name 'StreamingContext' could not be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Assets\Scripts\Save System\SaveData.cs(13,31): error CS0246: The type
> or namespace name 'PlaceableObjectData' could not be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Assets\Scripts\Save System\SaveData.cs(61,6): error CS0246: The type
> or namespace name 'OnDeserializedAttribute' could not be found (are
> you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Assets\Scripts\Save System\SaveData.cs(61,6): error CS0246: The type
> or namespace name 'OnDeserialized' could not be found (are you missing
> a using directive or an assembly reference?)

That is the script i'm working on:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;


[Serializable]

public class SaveData
{
    public static int IdCount;

    public Dictionary<string, PlaceableObjectsData> placeableObjectDatas =
        new Dictionary<string, PlaceableObjectsData>();

    public static string GenerateId()
    {
        IdCount++;
        return IdCount.ToString();

    }

     public void AddData(Data data)
    {
        if (data is placeableObjectDatas plObjData)

        {

            if (placeableObjectDatas.ContainsKey(plObjData.ID))
        {
            placeableObjectDatas[plObjData.ID] = plObjData;

        }
        else
        
        {
            placeableObjectDatas.Add(plObjData.ID, plObjData);
        }

        }

   }

      public void RemoveData(Data data)
       {

        if (data is placeableObjectDatas plObjData)

        {

            if (placeableObjectDatas.ContainsKey(plObjData.ID))
            {
                placeableObjectDatas.Remove(plObjData.ID);

            }

        }

    }

    [OnDeserialized]
    internal void OnDeserializedMethod(StreamingContext context)
    {
    placeableObjectDatas ??= new Dictionary<string, PlaceableObjectsData>();

    }

}
```

**EDIT:**

This is the script for PlaceableObjectData:

```
using System;
using UnityEngine;



public class PlaceableObjectsData : Data
{
    public string assetName;
    public Vector3 position;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

> Assets\Scripts\Save System\SaveSystem.cs(17,13): error CS0103: The
> name 'Directory' does not exist in the current context
>
> Assets\Scripts\Save System\SaveSystem.cs(20,13): error CS0103: The
> name 'Directory' does not exist in the current context
>
> Assets\Scripts\Save System\SaveData.cs(26,21): error CS0246: The type
> or namespace name 'placeableObjectDatas' could not be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Assets\Scripts\Save System\SaveSystem.cs(31,28): error CS0246: The
> type or namespace name 'JsonSerializerSettings' could not be found
> (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Assets\Scripts\Save System\SaveSystem.cs(32,42): error CS0103: The
> name 'ReferenceLoopHandling' does not exist in the current context
>
> Assets\Scripts\Save System\SaveSystem.cs(34,29): error CS0103: The
> name 'JsonConvert' does not exist in the current context
>
> Assets\Scripts\Save System\SaveSystem.cs(36,19): error CS1061:
> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'WriteAllText' and no
> accessible extension method 'WriteAllText' accepting a first argument
> of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
> an assembly reference?)
>
> Assets\Scripts\Save System\SaveData.cs(48,21): error CS0246: The type
> or namespace name 'placeableObjectDatas' could not be found (are you
> missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Assets\Scripts\Save System\SaveSystem.cs(42,22): error CS1061:
> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'Exists' and no accessible
> extension method 'Exists' accepting a first argument of type 'string'
> could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
> reference?)
>
> Assets\Scripts\Save System\SaveSystem.cs(45,42): error CS1061:
> 'string' does not contain a definition for 'ReadAllText' and no
> accessible extension method 'ReadAllText' accepting a first argument
> of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or
> an assembly reference?)
>
> Assets\Scripts\Save System\SaveSystem.cs(47,13): error CS0246: The
> type or namespace name 'saveData' could not be found (are you missing
> a using directive or an assembly reference?)
>
> Assets\Scripts\Save System\SaveSystem.cs(47,31): error CS0103: The
> name 'JsonConvert' does not exist in the current context
>
> Assets\Scripts\Save System\SaveSystem.cs(47,61): error CS0246: The
> type or namespace name 'saveData' could not be found (are you missing
> a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can fix error 1,3 and 4 by adding `using System.Runtime.Serialization;` at the top of File.

But I've never heard of PlaceableObjectData, is it maybe a custom class you have created in a other namespace ?            Then you have to also import that namespace with the `using` keyword.

Comment: thanks for the solution i still have only one error now Assets\Scripts\Save System\SaveData.cs(14,31): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PlaceableObjectData' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @kyloriusbeno You also have to import the namespace where `PlaceableObjectData` is defined, I dont know which namespace that is because you didn't provide the definition or said that the class is from a third party Library.

Comment: I edited the post you can see the script that has Placeable Object Data

Comment: @kyloriusbeno You made a small typo there, you have to correct "PlaceableObjectData" into "PlaceableObjectsData" in the first script file.

Comment: do i have to correct all the lines that contain this? because there is multiple lines with PlaceableObjectData or is it a specific line

Comment: @kyloriusbeno All

Comment: I edited the post with block of errors i got when i modified the PlaceableObjectsData.

Comment: @kyloriusbeno can you update the code with the changes you made.

Comment: okay done i updated both Scripts you can check them now

Answer (score 0):

this is the code y was making the error is in the line 7

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerController : MonoBehaviour
{
    private new RigidBody rigidbody;

    public float movementSpeed;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        rigidbody = GetComponent<RigidBody>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        float hor = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
        float ver = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

        if (hor != 0 || ver != 0) {
            Vector3 direction = (transform.forward * ver + transform.right * hor).normalized;

            rigidbody.velocity = direction * movementSpeed;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont know how to  make it help @peter

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).